# Bidirectional data structure conversion in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

**Note**: this is *not* a simple two-way map; the conversion is the important part.

I'm writing an application that will send and receive messages with a certain structure, which I must convert from and to an internal structure.

For example, the message:

```
{
    "Person": {
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }
    },
    "birth_date": "1997.01.12",
    "points": "330"
}
```

This must be converted to :

```
{ 
    "Person": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "birth": datetime.date(1997, 1, 12),
        "points": 330
    }
}
```

And vice-versa.

These messages have a lot of information, so I want to avoid having to manually write converters for both directions. Is there any way in Python to specify the mapping once, and use it for both cases?

In my research, I found an interesting Haskell library called [JsonGrammar](https://github.com/MedeaMelana/JsonGrammar2) which allows for this (it's for JSON, but that's irrelevant for the case). But my knowledge of Haskell isn't good enough to attempt a port.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I do not believe this is *just* a recommendation for tool / library. There is a question of how you can store / reverse transformation logic *without having to separately write forwards & backwards versions*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's actually quite an interesting problem. You could define a list of transformation, for example in the form `(key1, func_1to2, key2, func_2to1)`, or a similar format, where `key` could contain separators to indicate different levels of the dict, like `"Person.name.first"`.

```
noop = lambda x: x
relations = [("Person.name.first", noop, "Person.firstname", noop),
             ("Person.name.last", noop, "Person.lastname", noop),
             ("birth_date", lambda s: datetime.date(*map(int, s.split("."))),
              "Person.birth", lambda d: d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")),
             ("points", int, "Person.points", str)]
```

Then, iterate the elements in that list and transform the entries in the dictionary according to whether you want to go from form A to B or vice versa. You will also need some helper function for accessing keys in nested dictionaries using those dot-separated keys.

```
def deep_get(d, key):
    for k in key.split("."):
        d = d[k]
    return d

def deep_set(d, key, val):
    *first, last = key.split(".")
    for k in first:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[last] = val

def convert(d, mapping, atob):
    res = {}
    for a, x, b, y in mapping:
        a, b, f = (a, b, x) if atob else (b, a, y)
        deep_set(res, b, f(deep_get(d, a)))
    return res
```

Example:

```
>>> d1 = {"Person": { "name": { "first": "John", "last": "Smith" } },
...       "birth_date": "1997.01.12",
...       "points": "330" }
...
>>> print(convert(d1, relations, True))    
{'Person': {'birth': datetime.date(1997, 1, 12),
            'firstname': 'John',
            'lastname': 'Smith',
            'points': 330}}
```

Comment: Nice, and only in an handful of lines! Thanks! The only thing thing that saddens me is that specific subtransformations (e.g. the `name` structure ←→ pair of keys `lastname` and `firstname`) can't be reused if they also appear in another part of the message.

Comment: @AndréParamés Good point. That might also be possible, using recursion. E.g. you could just define a mapping for key `"Person"` and as the function specify a function that again calls `convert` with a different mapping. But in this case this is difficult, as there are other keys that "switch" dictionary levels.

Answer (score 8):

Tobias has answered it quite well. If you are looking for a library that ensures the Model Transformation dynamically then you can explore the Python's Model transformation library [PyEcore](https://github.com/pyecore/pyecore).

PyEcore allows you to handle models and metamodels (structured data model), and gives the key you need for building ModelDrivenEngineering-based tools and other applications based on a structured data model. It supports out-of-the-box:

Data inheritance,
Two-ways relationship management (opposite references),
XMI (de)serialization,
JSON (de)serialization etc

**Edit**

I have found something more interesting for you with example similar to yours, check out [JsonBender](https://github.com/Onyo/jsonbender).

```
import json
from jsonbender import bend, K, S

MAPPING = {
    'Person': {
        'firstname': S('Person', 'name', 'first'),
        'lastname': S('Person', 'name', 'last'),
        'birth': S('birth_date'),
        'points': S('points')
    }
}

source = {
    "Person": {
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }
        },
    "birth_date": "1997.01.12",
    "points": "330"
}

result = bend(MAPPING, source)
print(json.dumps(result))
```

Output:

```
{"Person": {"lastname": "Smith", "points": "330", "firstname": "John", "birth": "1997.01.12"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds interesting; do you know of any examples similar to the case here? I have to admit I feel a bit lost reading that page.

Comment: @AndréParamés Yes I know this can be really complicated. That's why I explicitly mentioned its based on Model Driven Design Engineering. I couldn't find the practical example for specifically your case or something similar but I have found something simple that might be interesting for you. I am mentioning in the answers.

Comment: Thanks, JsonBender certainly seems interesting. Is it bidirectional, though?

Comment: Well you can create Bi Directional mappings :) I have done one directional mapping for you . It seems pretty clean blackbox thing. Still ping me if need help.

Comment: Sure, but my goal was to avoid having to write both :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169875/discussion-between-noor-ali-jafri-and-andre-parames).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this (converter lambdas and dot-based notation idea taken from [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k)):

```
import datetime

converters = {
    (str, datetime.date): lambda s: datetime.date(*map(int, s.split("."))),
    (datetime.date, str): lambda d: d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d"),
}
mapping = [
    ('Person.name.first', str, 'Person.firstname', str),
    ('Person.name.last', str, 'Person.lastname', str),
    ('birth_date', str, 'Person.birth', datetime.date),
    ('points', str, 'Person.points', int),
]

def covert_doc(doc, mapping, converters, inverse=False):
    converted = {}
    for keys1, type1, keys2, type2 in mapping:
        if inverse:
            keys1, type1, keys2, type2 = keys2, type2, keys1, type1
        converter = converters.get((type1, type2), type2)
        keys1 = keys1.split('.')
        keys2 = keys2.split('.')
        obj1 = doc
        while keys1:
            k, *keys1 = keys1
            obj1 = obj1[k]
        dict2 = converted
        while len(keys2) > 1:
            k, *keys2 = keys2
            dict2 = dict2.setdefault(k, {})
        dict2[keys2[0]] = converter(obj1)
    return converted

# Test
doc1 = {
    "Person": {
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }
    },
    "birth_date": "1997.01.12",
    "points": "330"
}
doc2 = {
    "Person": {
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "birth": datetime.date(1997, 1, 12),
        "points": 330
    }
}
assert doc2 == covert_doc(doc1, mapping, converters)
assert doc1 == covert_doc(doc2, mapping, converters, inverse=True)
```

This nice things are that you can reuse converters (even to convert different document structures) and that you only need to define non-trivial conversions. The drawback is that, as it is, every pair of types must always use the same conversion (maybe it could be extended to add optional alternative conversions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use lists to describe paths to values in objects with type converting functions, for example:

```
from_paths = [
    (['Person', 'name', 'first'], None),
    (['Person', 'name', 'last'], None),
    (['birth_date'], lambda s: datetime.date(*map(int, s.split(".")))),
    (['points'], lambda s: int(s))
]
to_paths = [
    (['Person', 'firstname'], None),
    (['Person', 'lastname'], None),
    (['Person', 'birth'], lambda d: d.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")),
    (['Person', 'points'], str)
]
```

and a little function to covert from and to (much like tobias suggests but without string separation and using `reduce` to get values from dict):

```
def convert(from_paths, to_paths, obj):
    to_obj = {}
    for (from_keys, convfn), (to_keys, _) in zip(from_paths, to_paths):
        value = reduce(operator.getitem, from_keys, obj)
        if convfn:
            value = convfn(value)
        curr_lvl_dict = to_obj
        for key in to_keys[:-1]:
            curr_lvl_dict = curr_lvl_dict.setdefault(key, {})
        curr_lvl_dict[to_keys[-1]] = value
    return to_obj
```

test:

```
from_json = '''{
    "Person": {
        "name": {
            "first": "John",
            "last": "Smith"
        }
    },
    "birth_date": "1997.01.12",
    "points": "330"
}'''
>>> obj = json.loads(from_json)
>>> new_obj = convert(from_paths, to_paths, obj)
>>> new_obj
{'Person': {'lastname': u'Smith',
            'points': 330,
            'birth': datetime.date(1997, 1, 12), 'firstname': u'John'}}
>>> convert(to_paths, from_paths, new_obj)
{'birth_date': '1997.01.12',
 'Person': {'name': {'last': u'Smith', 'first': u'John'}},
 'points': '330'}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, but my goal was to avoid having to write the conversion for each direction, I want to write only one that goes "both ways".